# Show all notification after being online in fcm

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

There is an Android project using FCM

Notifications sent from the server correctly, the issue is when the android device is
offline and after being online it shows only the last notification, not all of them

```
class FCMService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    private val TAG = "TAG_TAG"

    override fun onNewToken(p0: String) {
        super.onNewToken(p0)
        Log.d(TAG, "FCMService --> onNewToken --> Message New Token: $p0")
    }

    override fun onMessageReceived(p0: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(p0)
        var one = ""
        var two = ""
        var groupId = ""
        if (p0.data.isNotEmpty()) {
            p0.data.keys.forEach { key ->
                if (key == "one") {
                    one = p0.data.getOrDefault(key, "N/A")
                } else if (key == "two") {
                    two = p0.data.getOrDefault(key, "N/A")
                }
            }
        }
        sendNotification(p0.notification!!.body!!, one, two)
    }

    private fun sendNotification(
        messageBody: String,
        one: String,
        two: String,
    ) {
        val intent = Intent(this, NotificationActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        intent.putExtra("one", one)
        intent.putExtra("two", two)
        val uniqueInt = getUniqueInt()
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            applicationContext, uniqueInt, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )
        val defaultSoundUri: Uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
        val chanelId = "256"
        val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(
            applicationContext
        )
        createChanelId(notificationManager, chanelId)
        val notificationBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this,
            chanelId
        )
        notificationBuilder
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setChannelId(chanelId)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .priority = NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH
        notificationManager.notify(getUniqueInt(), notificationBuilder.build())
    }

    private fun getUniqueInt(): Int {
        return (System.currentTimeMillis() and 0xff).toInt()
    }

    private fun createChanelId(notificationManager: NotificationManagerCompat, channelId: String) {
        val channelDescription = "FCM Channel"
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            var notificationChannel: NotificationChannel? =
                notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(channelId)
            if (notificationChannel == null) {
                val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH //Set the importance level
                notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(channelId, channelDescription, importance)
                notificationChannel.lightColor = Color.GREEN //Set if it is necesssary
                notificationChannel.enableVibration(true) //Set if it is necesssary
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Same issue, what should I do?